# Which is the main meaning of 与える?

Tags: words, verbs

I would like to know which is the main meaning of the verb 与える ? According to the dictionary it means several things: "give", "feed", "bestow", "set homework", "harm". Are all these actions frequently expressed with 与える? Please feel free to give example sentences.

Thank you so much in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that the main meaning is "to give", in the sense of eg: "to give a shock" or "to give an opportunity", and so on.

Examples for "to give an opportunity": [機会を与える](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%A9%9F%E4%BC%9A%E3%82%92%E4%B8%8E%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B)

Examples for "to give a shock": [ショックを与える](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%92%E4%B8%8E%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B)

Comment: でも「ハトに餌を与えないでください」とかよく看板ありますよね・・

Comment: There are certainly other usages, as mentioned by the OP. I'm just giving my impression of what is the most basic usage.